# How to bind a value to an ObservableList's size?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-bindings

I want to bind a value to the `ObservableList`'s size to know its size and also to know if it has multiple values

```
private ObservableList<String> strings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They can be bound with the `Bindings` class:

```
ObservableList<String> strings = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
IntegerBinding sizeProperty = Bindings.size(strings);
BooleanBinding multipleElemsProperty = new BooleanBinding() {
    @Override protected boolean computeValue() {
        return strings.size() > 1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is correct. I will provide additional insight for the benefit of interested readers.

[`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)
 is an interface and as such does not hold a `size` property.
 [`ListExpression`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/ListExpression.html)
 is an abstract class implementing `ObservableList` and adding [`ReadOnlyIntegerProperty size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/ListExpression.html#sizeProperty)
 and
 [`ReadOnlyBooleanProperty empty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/ListExpression.html#emptyProperty)
 properties. This class is the base class for a whole inheritance tree of list properties classes.

Most users will not want to subclass the abstract classes in the tree themselves, so we'll look at the provided concrete implementation:

```
ListExpression                    (abstract)
 - ReadOnlyListProperty           (abstract)
    - ListProperty                (abstract)
      - ListPropertyBase          (abstract)
        - SimpleListProperty
          - ReadOnlyListWrapper
```

[`SimpleListProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleListProperty.html)
 is, as its name suggests, a simple list property - an `ObservableList` wrapped in a `Property`. It is the parallel of the other `SimpleXxxProperty`s. It also has a subclass
 [`ReadOnlyListWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyListWrapper.html)
 to handle read-only and read-and-write requirements. It can be constructed from an `ObservableList`:

```
SimpleListProperty<String> list = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
IntegerProperty intProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
intProperty.bind(list.sizeProperty());
```

Users which need the benefits from this class (over just using `ObservableList`) and decide to use it do not need the static [`Bindings#size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#size-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) approach.

Comment: Great answer !! First time i have seen `ListExpression` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/ListExpression.html

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS You will probably never see `ListExpression` in code since it's very low level and few will need to use it directly. `SimpleListProperty` and `ReadOnlyListWrapper`, on the other hand, are quite useful out-of-the-box.

Comment: Already added it into the code :) . I need to bind the maximum value of a ScrollBar to the Size of an `Observable List - 1`

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS `SimpleListProperty` is enough for this.